# Discord.py How to add author avatar in embed message?

Tags: discord.py

I have this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before:discord.Member, after:discord.Member):
    role = before.guild.get_role(xxxxxxx)
    channel = before.guild.get_channel(xxxxxx)
    gif_url = "xxxxx"
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
      embed = discord.Embed(
            color = discord.Color.from_rgb(28, 60, 128))
      embed.set_image(url=gif_url)
      await channel.send(f'<@{after.id}> **get role, cool!**', embed=embed)
```

And I want to add author icon of user, which achieve role

I know, I can use

```
embed.set_author(name="", icon_url="")
```

But I don't know, how I can get an avatar of certain user.

Comment: To get the avatar URL of a certain user (in this case, the user who received the role), you can use the `avatar_url` attribute of the `Member` object. In your situation, you can get the avatar URL of the `after` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member.avatar.url` is used to get the avatar url and in your case `after` is a Member object.

```
embed.set_author(name = after.name, icon_url = after.avatar.url)
```

This will add the author's name and avatar to the embed.

Also, ensure you have enabled the 'Server Members' intent on your bot application. You can read more on gateway intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solve it

```
embed.set_author(name="xxx", icon_url = after.avatar.url)
```

That's work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).